# Remove style attribute from HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, tinymce

I'm not too good with regular expressions, but with PHP I'm wanting to remove the `style` attribute from HTML tags in a string that's coming back from TinyMCE.

So change `<p style="...">Text</p>` to just vanilla `<p>Test</p>`.

How would I achieve this with something like the `preg_replace()` function?

Comment: If regular expressions aren't recommended for this task, then what *is*?

Comment: When the html string comes back from TinyMCE, you do not just want to remove a single attribute or manually look over the DOM tree. Use HTMLPurifier, which can be configured to strip out style= attributes.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The pragmatic regex `(<[^>]+) style=".*?"` will solve this problem in all reasonable cases. The part of the match that is not the first captured group should be removed, like this:

```
$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $input);
```

Match a `<` followed by one or more "not `>`" until we come to `space` and the `style="..."` part. The `/i` makes it work even with `STYLE="..."`. Replace this match with `$1`, which is the captured group. It will leave the tag as is, if the tag doesn't include `style="..."`.

Comment: +1 --- Just used this to get rid of style spam that occurs in Google Sites pages when users do pastes of text in the smart editor without using "Paste as plain text" in their browser. I used Notepad++ and the replace command. For Notepad++, the format is `\1` and not `$1`.

Comment: does not work when style is escaped. It should be either refactored to make it work or $input should be replaced with stripcslashes($input)

Comment: You can run this command twice .. once for double quotes .. and then simply modify it for single quotes and run it again.

Comment: GREAT!! Just what I needed

Comment: I am using angular js text editor   and  i got a value from that text editor and it is inserted in mysql as       <div><span  initial; font-family: inherit;">Rent this White PVC tent for your outdoor events and parties or Ramadan Iftaars. Available on Rent in Dubai.&nbsp;</span><br></div><div>Aluminium structure PVC tent of size 10M x 10M available on rent in Dubai.Ideal for parties and ramadan functions.</div>      The problem is  <span  initial; font-family: inherit;">   it have no style keyword   so how to solve this?

Comment: Careful about @AdslLe 's solution: it will produce unexpected results with `style='font-family: "Open Sans"'`. Running it twice (once with `'`, and once with `"`) works fine.

Comment: @QuentinS. `(<[^>]+) style=("|').*?("|')?.*("|')\s`
https://regex101.com/r/umCK9M/1

Answer (score 39):

Something like this should work (untested code warning):

```
<?php

$html = '<p style="asd">qwe</p><br /><p class="qwe">qweqweqwe</p>';

$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->query("//p[@style]");

foreach($items as $item) {
  $item->removeAttribute("style");
}

echo $domd->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Further to my comment above... It does work but DOMDocument has trouble with html entities. It will convert them to utf8 characters. So &amp;trade; becomes TM. In the end I used simplehtmldom and have put my function as an answer...

Answer (score 28):

I commented on @Mayerln 's function. It does work but DOMDocument really stuffs with encoding. Here's my simplehtmldom version

```
function stripAttributes($html,$attribs) {
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($html);
    foreach($attribs as $attrib)
        foreach($dom->find("*[$attrib]") as $e)
            $e->$attrib = null; 
    $dom->load($dom->save());
    return $dom->save();
}
```

Comment: Can confirm, this works superb! (thank you for saving my day)

Comment: Can this be enhanced to remove any and all attributes?

Comment: Why `$dom->load($dom->save());`?

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
<?php

$html = '<p style="border: 1px solid red;">Test</p>';
echo preg_replace('/<p style="(.+?)">(.+?)<\/p>/i', "<p>$2</p>", $html);

?>
```

By the way, as pointed out by others, regex are not suggested for this.

Comment: `<p   style="something-evil">` - BOOM. `<p foo="bar" style="something-evil">` - BOOM.

Comment: That was obviously crafted on the example reported in the original question. You can anyway improve the regex using something like this: 
preg_replace('/<p(.*?)style="(.+?)"(.*?)>(.+?)<\/p>/i', "<p>$4</p>", $links); and get no BOOM :)

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon thanks. I have just added the reverse match based on your commented regex.

Answer (score 4):

I use this:

```
function strip_word_html($text, $allowed_tags = '<a><ul><li><b><i><sup><sub><em><strong><u><br><br/><br /><p><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6>')
{
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    //replace MS special characters first
    $search = array('/&lsquo;/u', '/&rsquo;/u', '/&ldquo;/u', '/&rdquo;/u', '/&mdash;/u');
    $replace = array('\'', '\'', '"', '"', '-');
    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
    //make sure _all_ html entities are converted to the plain ascii equivalents - it appears
    //in some MS headers, some html entities are encoded and some aren't
    //$text = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    //try to strip out any C style comments first, since these, embedded in html comments, seem to
    //prevent strip_tags from removing html comments (MS Word introduced combination)
    if(mb_stripos($text, '/*') !== FALSE){
        $text = mb_eregi_replace('#/\*.*?\*/#s', '', $text, 'm');
    }
    //introduce a space into any arithmetic expressions that could be caught by strip_tags so that they won't be
    //'<1' becomes '< 1'(note: somewhat application specific)
    $text = preg_replace(array('/<([0-9]+)/'), array('< $1'), $text);
    $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);
    //eliminate extraneous whitespace from start and end of line, or anywhere there are two or more spaces, convert it to one
    $text = preg_replace(array('/^\s\s+/', '/\s\s+$/', '/\s\s+/u'), array('', '', ' '), $text);
    //strip out inline css and simplify style tags
    $search = array('#<(strong|b)[^>]*>(.*?)</(strong|b)>#isu', '#<(em|i)[^>]*>(.*?)</(em|i)>#isu', '#<u[^>]*>(.*?)</u>#isu');
    $replace = array('<b>$2</b>', '<i>$2</i>', '<u>$1</u>');
    $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
    //on some of the ?newer MS Word exports, where you get conditionals of the form 'if gte mso 9', etc., it appears
    //that whatever is in one of the html comments prevents strip_tags from eradicating the html comment that contains
    //some MS Style Definitions - this last bit gets rid of any leftover comments */
    $num_matches = preg_match_all("/\<!--/u", $text, $matches);
    if($num_matches){
        $text = preg_replace('/\<!--(.)*--\>/isu', '', $text);
    }
    $text = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $text);
return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using such thing to clean-up the style='...' section out of tags with keeping of other attributes at the moment.

```
$output = preg_replace('/<([^>]+)(\sstyle=(?P<stq>["\'])(.*)\k<stq>)([^<]*)>/iUs', '<$1$5>', $input);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Lorenzo Marcon's answer:

Using `preg_replace` to select everything except style attribute:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(<p.+?)style=".+?"(>.+?)/i', "$1$2", $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = preg_replace('/\sstyle=("|\').*?("|\')/i', '', $html);
```

For replacing all style="" with blank.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the regex answers to work, and noticed a few comments recommending against them anyway.

My simple solution was just to disable the style attributes with:

```
$html = str_replace(' style=', ' data-mso-style=', $html);
```

I realise it's not what the question is asking, but it might help someone else.

Answer (score -8):

You could handle it client side, the easiest would be with jQuery. Something like:

```
$("#tinyMce p").removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: That's insecure as the user can still tamper with the data submitted to the server.

Comment: The original poster asked how to do this with PHP, not javascript. Quote: "...but with PHP I'm wanting to remove the style attribute..."