# How to remove all style attributes using jquery and also in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [php regexp: remove all attributes from an html tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/php-regexp-remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag)
>   [Remove style attribute from HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags)

EDITED:

For example i am having the following content:

```
    <div style="text-indent: -76.5pt; margin: 0in 54.9pt 0pt 76.5pt;"><strong>Motion with Constant Acceleration</strong></div>
```

**I need to *remove* all style attributes using jQuery and PHP**

My output should look like this:

```
    <div style=""><strong>Motion with Constant Acceleration</strong></div>
```

**OR**

```
    <div><strong>Motion with Constant Acceleration</strong></div>
```

How can this be done.. Any help will be thankful and grateful...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: red pill or blue pill (jQuery or PHP) make your choice.

Comment: it really depends if you want to do it in php or jquery. In PHP you could use preg_replace to remove the style attribute ... whilst in jQuery you could use .removeAttr("style");

Comment: I need know how it can be done using both of it... Shall any one explain me...

Answer (score 14):

jQuery option would be

```
$('*[style]').attr('style', ''); 
// sets style attribute to empty string on all elements that have it
```

PHP is referred in comments

Answer (score 7):

Use not selector to exclude table

```
$("*[style]").not("table").removeAttr("style");
```

or

```
$("*[style]").not("table").attr("style", "");
```

Comment: Even though your version is completely valid, I think using negation in the selector makes it more concise and comprehensible. I.e. `$("*[style]:not(table)").removeAttr("style");`