# How to strip Style Attributes from HTML Tags?

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I want to remove all styles from tags with PHP.

For example.

Original:

`<body style="color:back;">`

Final:

`<body>`

Here's a example:

```
$body_htm='<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>[Some Title] some text...</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #F2F2F2; color: #222; font-family: georgia,serif; letter-spacing: -0.01em; line-height: 1.25; margin-bottom: 0.55em; font-size: 1.2em;">
<div style="background-color: #F2F2F2; border: 2px dotted #333; padding: 55px 0 55px 55px;">
<div style="background-color: #F2F2F2; width: 400px;">
<p style="margin-bottom:110px;"><b>Hello!!!</b></p>';
```

It should return this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>[Some Title] some text...</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div>
<p><b>Hello!!!</b></p>';
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplication of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags

Comment: The thread the purists are indicating has no chosen answers!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very simple replace will probably do:

```
preg_replace( '/style=(["\'])[^\1]*?\1/i', '', $subject, -1 );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This will do but the resulting tags are ending with a space, see: `<body >
<div >
<div >
<p >`

Comment: I inserted a space in front of `/ style` and it did the trick.

Comment: ah cool. It wasn't that complete i guess, Also, will not handle properly if the attribute looked like style = "color: #fff". When there's some whitespace between attribute and value etc.

Comment: This really helped, thank you!  Other (more complex) solutions I've seen somehow leave tags open that totally mangle the rest of my layout.

Comment: What if I want to strip all properties, values of the "style" attribute and replace it with a different attribute, such as "class" attribute? Right now you are removing the style attribute, but I need to remove all of it's content and replace it with class attribute. How do I go about that?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't stop the `style` attributes from being inserted in the first place, I'd suggest something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/). It's a well developed solution for exactly this kind of problem, and also allows you to perform more HTML filtering in the future (XSS prevention, for instance) with minimum effort.

Problems can be created by using a regular expression solution, usually necessitating more and more complex regular expressions to rectify until you've essentially recreated something like HTML Purifier yourself (and lost your mind in the process). Using the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension can also create problems if you are handed invalid markup. While HTML Purifier is probably not perfect in every way, it will do what you need and is supported.

Comment: Thank you for the "HTML Purifier" tip! But for my actual need, a simple preg_replace did the job.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cant you modify the output, that the style-tag is not included (inline-styles are anyway bad practice)?
2. Is it possible to include your own CSS and override the body properties with an `!important` rule to modify *your* output?
3. If answered both question with "no", then use a regex or a DOM/XML-Parser to remove it.

Comment: That's tru but not for all scenarios. For example, Gmail doesn't read yet styles in the head of HTML documents. See: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Using `!important`, let alone relying on it to prevent layout breakage, is bad practice and will make any designer or front-end developer want to do bad things to you. Two wrongs never make a right (counteracting style attributes with `!important`).