# How to remove all 'alt' attribute from all the <img> tags from HTML file in PHP?

Tags: php, image, alt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove style attribute from HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags)

Current image looks like

```
<img src="images/sample.jpg" alt="xyz"/>
```

Now I want to remove all such alt tags present in all the tags in HTML file, the PHP code itself should replace all the alt attribute appearances.
The output should be like
`<img src="images/sample.jpg" />` only
How can be done with php?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Have you read about [DOM](http://php.net/dom) in PHP ?

Comment: +2 - really?  What is it in this question that deserves upvote??

Comment: Idea: Parse the HTML into a DOM and use an XSL-Transformation on it. That would have a template like <xsl:template match="img/@alt"><!-- no output --></xsl:template> in it, and simply copy all the other stuff.

Comment: @Touki I'll read about DOM.

Comment: just an FYI, but the `alt` attribute is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for HTML parsing/manipulation. The example below reads a HTML file, removes the `alt` attribute from all `img` tags, then prints out the HTML.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('file.html');

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image)
{
    $image->removeAttribute('alt');
}

echo $dom->saveHTML(); // print the modified HTML
```

Comment: Thnks @MrCode for your help. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Read your file. You can use file_get_contents() to read a file

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('filename.html');
$fileContent = preg_replace('/alt=\"(.*)\"/', '', $fileContent);
file_put_contents('filename.html', $fileContent);
```

Make sure your file is writable

Comment: -1 for [using regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1607098). - *Edition corrected the regexp*

Comment: Thank you Touki. It may be not the best way, but it works ...

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get a hold on the document source you want to modify. It's not clear if you want to edit some html files on your server, edit the html output generated by a request or what...

In this answer I'm gonna step over on how you get to the HTML. It could be a `file_get_contents('filename.html');` or [some magic with output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

Since [you don't want to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) you need to use a parser:

Since the `alt` attribute is required for the HTML to be valid, if you want to "remove" it you have to set it to an empty string.

This should work:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML($myhtml);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img'); 

foreach($images as $img) {
    $image->setAttribute('alt', '');
}

$myhtml = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

For valid xHTML it should have the alt attribute.

Something like this would work:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($doc);   // $doc is the html document.
foreach ($xml->xpath('//img') as $img_tag) {
    if (isset($img_tag->attributes()->alt)) {
        unset($img_tag->attributes()->alt);
    }
}
$new_doc = $xml->asXML();
```