# How to replace image unwanted content

Tags: php

In my comment box people are going tricky, They are using style to fix image out side of comment box. For example:

```
Hellow how are you? <br>
<img src="http://example.com/image/gifts/19.png" style="position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 150px;">
```

So I want to remove this extra code. I am trying with `preg_replace` and `str_replace` but I am not getting any where.

I want it as:

```
Hellow how are you? <br>
<img src="http://example.com/image/gifts/19.png">
```

I want to remove this style part from it.

I try this it works as well but it will be so long if I keep writing in uppercase and lowercase

**PHP:**

```
function unwant($text)
{
    $unwant = array(
       'style' => '',    
       'Style' => '',
       'STYle' => '',
       'STYLe' => '',
       'STYLE' => ''
    );
    return str_replace(array_keys($unwant), array_values($unwant), $text);
}
```

I want to remove it : `style="position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 150px;"`

Is there a better way to do it?

**2. And another thing**

If a user only posts an image URL

```
http://example.com/image/gifts/19.png
```

I want it to replace with

```
<img src="http://example.com/image/gifts/19.png">
```

Comment: FYI, if you think using the `style` attribute is bad for your site, wait till people use XSS by using the `onload` attribute to run javascript.

Comment: You may use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Little hint: `'#(<[^>]+?)(style="[^"]")?([^>]+?>)#i'` => `"$1$3"`

Comment: @Termis he doesn't want to strip the tags, only the attrs

Comment: @bwoebi Oh! sorry, I misunderstand it!

Comment: here the first answer does what you want. as @bwoebi mentioned, you can use regex here to remove the unwanted style attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags

Comment: thanks for so many quick details everyone :)

Comment: If they can do that you have a serious flaw with your site, what if they do `http://example.com/image/gifts/19.png"><script>alert("i'm a hackurrrr");</script>`

Answer (score 1):

For point 1 its while you can strip out stuff using str_replace or preg_match etc, alternatively you could parse the DOM and deal with nodes that way

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $image->removeAttributeNode('style');
}
$cleanHtml = $doc->saveHtml();
```

However, for security I would investigate using BBCode or Markdown for your comments and then converting to HTML in your code. This could allow you more control over what is output on your site while still allowing commenters some freedom in formatting their posts

Answer (score 0):

Use a proven and tested *HTML whitelisting* library like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org). Regular expressions are not suited to parse and modify HTML.