# Regex remove BR style

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to delete all "style" atributes from my `<br />` tag, but I don't know where I'm making mistake

`$a = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '<br />', $a);`

so if I got `<br style="line-height: 37px;" />` i need to convert it to `<br />`. And the same is with all `BR` style attribute. how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove style attribute from HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags)

Comment: i saw it, I can't modify it to `br`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do this using regular expression anyways, but if you insist..

```
$text = preg_replace('~<br\K\s*style="[^"]*"~i', '', $text);
```

Comment: Doesn't work when css is delimited by single quotes, equals sign has spaces around it, and when style attribute is not the first attribute. Also, what's wrong with using regular expressions here?