# strip_tags or other solution

Tags: php, strip-tags

I have this text in mysql adding even directly but do not want to lose the labels only the styles and formats that tenien

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;"><span style="line-height: 1.428571429;">Allí, el club crema</span><p>
```

use `strip_tags` but removes the entire label

```
strip_tags ($ data, "<p>");
```

I want it that way:

```
<p>Allí, el club crema<p>
```

I hope your help, thank you very much beforehand for your answers

Comment: You want an html parser that has the ability to strip attributes. I wouldn't trust a strip_tags or regex solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove style attribute from HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Warning, anti-pattern: using REGEX on mark-up is generally a bad idea. However it's sometimes more convenient, so to hell with it:

```
$data = preg_replace('/(<\w+) [^>]+/', '$1', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no php function for that. The strip tags function will strip the tag completely, and allowing a tag will keep the tag in place, *including* the attributes. You'll need to load the html in a xml parser and reconstruct the output, or, and I would advise you to go that way, use regex to strip out any html attributes (after you've stripped away the tags you don't need anyway. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026096/remove-all-attributes-from-an-html-tag)