# How to remove all img tag in php variable?

Tags: php, html, string, text

How to remove all `img` tag in this php var? I have `$text` php var like this.

```
$text = '<p>test test test&nbsp;</p><p><img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/f380ecc42410414693b467ac7a97901b.png" style="width: 728px;"><br></p><p>test test</p><p><img src="http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/f380ecc42410414693b467ac7a97901b.png" style="width: 728px;"><br></p>';
```

I want to remove all `img` tag in this `$text` php var using php, how can i do that ?

Comment: is this your text or HTML?

Comment: Not clear what are you asking for?

Comment: Can you show something that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex you can do it. Php [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) can replace specific text with another. You can use it. The code replace all `img` tag with empty.

```
$text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+>/", "", $text);
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/NVcIF)

Comment: @mamamamamongmongmongmong Style attribute is in `img` that removeing.

Comment: I mean i want to remove all Style attribute outside img tag too

Comment: Or i have to ask a new question ?

Comment: @mamamamamongmongmongmong I can answer to it but that is better to ask new querstion.

Comment: @mamamamamongmongmongmong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

if you meant to extract attributes, try
     
    `$url="reffile.html";
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html));

$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
```