# how to remove all style class from html code and selective html tag from string?

Tags: php

```
<p>
    <!--StartFragment-->
    <ul style="box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0px 0px 10px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; color: rgb(65, 65, 65); font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', 'sans-serif'; font-size: 17px;">
        <li style="box-sizing: border-box; margin-top: 7px;">Fast Performance:&nbsp;Scripts written in PHP usually execute faster than those written in other scripting languages like ASP.NET or JSP.</li>
        <li style="box-sizing: border-box; margin-top: 7px;">Vast Community:&nbsp;Since PHP is supported by the worldwide community, finding help or documentation for PHP online is extremely easy.</li>   
    </ul>
    <!--EndFragment-->  
    <span id="sceditor-start-marker" class="sceditor-selection sceditor-ignore" style="display: none; line-height: 0;"> </span>
    <span id="sceditor-end-marker" class="sceditor-selection sceditor-ignore" style="display: none; line-height: 0;"> </span><br>
</p>
```

**how to remove all style class from html code and selective html tag from string ?**
like i dont want to remove `<p>,<a>,<b>`

```
$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $output);
    $output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) class=".*?"/i', '$1', $output);
    $answer = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) id=".*?"/i', '$1', $output);
```

i found this way to remove style and class but its seems bad

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where does the HTML come from?

Comment: HTML is generated from sceditor

Comment: Use a legitimate DOM parser, not regex.  Start building your solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5517572/2943403

Answer (score 1):

To remove the styles use this regex - `$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=("|\').*?("|\')/i','$1',$output);`

To remove the classes use this regex - `$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) class=("|\').*?("|\')/i','$1',$output);`

To remove all tags except the whitelisted - `$output = strip_tags($output, '<p><a><b><i><table><tr><td><ul><ol><li><hr><h1><h2><h3><pre><caption><br><span><img>')`

Also look here [Remove style attribute from HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags)