# How to define style attribute when html is in double quotes (as String)

Tags: html, css

My question is very straight forward. I am trying to put style attribute in a html which is in string format. Through a method i am passing html code in string format. And later i am suppose to add a css in that depending on the situation.

I tried:

```
"<div style='background-color: red'>'Some data'</div>"   // didnt help
```

```
"<div style=&quot;background-color: red;&quot;>'Some data'</div>"   // didnt help
```

In the end:

```
if(somethingMatches){
   data = data.replace('something', "<mark style='background-color: red;'>" + 'something' + "</mark>")
}
```

Is there some way that i can pull it off...

Comment: Could you please post some of your code more to help understand the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004168/escape-quotes-in-javascript)

Comment: my question is that, when html is in string format, can we still do inline styling to it. As of now, its not accepting inline styling in single quotes...

Comment: May be usefull for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517255/remove-style-attribute-from-html-tags

Comment: @TrickOrTreat it doesn't matter single or double quotes. `style='background-color: red'` is working as expected. Probably you have error some where else

Comment: escape character is not helping, i already used `"<mark style=\"background-color: red;\">", "</mark>"`

Comment: @Arseniy-II quite possible, but code is only this much for this case, what all mistakes i can make here...

Comment: I think, style is not suppose to be treated as a string, but how should i express this in codes...

Comment: What do you mean `html in string format` ? Are you using javascript then  show your full code

Comment: single or double quotes should make that work. Can you post some of your codes

Comment: i wish i could say it works!!

Comment: @TrickOrTreat that should be working. Is your `if` statement working

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way:

```js
var data = document.body.innerHTML;
data = data.replace(/something/g, "<mark style='background-color: red;'>" + 'something' + "</mark>");
document.body.innerHTML = data;
```

```html
my name is something<br>
something is going on
```

If you want to replace all matching words then you should use [Regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) in JavaScript